# Canvas Calendar Template with Multiple Calendars

Tags: calendar, powerapps-canvas

I'm in a SPO environment I have a requirement to make 3 training room scheduling calendars. 121A, 121B, 121C, rolled into calendar, with a Canvas Apps look.

I have a couple of options, I can create a legacy "calendar" or use a list and import the "calendar columns" as they have recurrence.  Which is needed if you're needing to do weekly training schedules with groups.

They all have the basic "Title, Start Date, End Date, Recurrence, Choice (meeting, training, VIP)"

For testing purposes I've creates a 121A list and 121A calendar to see which would be easier to integrate.

I've been playing around with the Canvas Calendar Template, as the heavy lifting has been done.  I've kind of connected both of them but there is a lot of back end changes that need to be made.

I'm hoping for some guidance please.

Thanks